# Copying Column to next one

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My Goal is to get a Macro that copies the whole Column R and pastes it into the next Column S. When i use the button again, the column R gets copied and it should be pasted into the column T.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet


Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

copySheet.Range("R:R").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But when I use the macro, the column gets copied, but it doesn't move to the next column and never gets pasted into the column R.

Comment: Is there anything in cell R1? If not, the right-most column will not update.

Comment: I recommend reading [How to avoid copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611707/16578424) - if you apply those adivses, the error will most likely be gone.

Comment: `never gets pasted into the column R.` You don't want to paste it there, do you?

Comment: Data starts at R4. Everytime I use the Button it should be pasted into the next available blank column.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid empty cell issue use this

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet


Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

copySheet.Range("R:R").Copy
pasteSheet.Columns(pasteSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1).PasteSpecial


Application.CutCopyMode = False  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Entire Column

```vb
Sub CopyEntireColumn()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet: Set copySheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet: Set pasteSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim copyRange As Range: Set copyRange = copySheet.Columns("R")
    
    Dim pasteRange As Range:
    
    With pasteSheet.UsedRange
        Set pasteRange = .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count).EntireColumn
    End With
    
    copyRange.Copy pasteRange
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Instead of introducing the range variables, you could use the shorter but less readable
(not recommended):

```
With pasteSheet.UsedRange
    copySheet.Columns("R").Copy .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count).EntireColumn
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy paste.

```
Sub copyRange()

Dim xLAppL As Excel.Application: Set xLAppL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Dim wrkBk As Excel.Workbook: Set wrkBk = xLAppL.ActiveWorkbook
Dim wrksH As Worksheet: Set wrksH = wrkBk.ActiveSheet


Dim sourceArr() As Variant: sourceArr = wrksH.Range("r:r").Value2 '.CurrentRegion

    wrksH.Range("T1").Resize(UBound(sourceArr, 1), UBound(sourceArr, 2)).Value2 = sourceArr

End Sub
```